# Rendering data based on route prefix

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is there a way in VueRouter to determine the routes prefix...

For example I have a navigation component that I'd like to render some user related links on only if the route begins with

> /user-settings/

So for example

> /user-settings/payment
>   /user-settings/profile

If the user-settings prefix is not on the route it will render the standard navigation links. I know I'll have to have a v-if and v-else on the navigation component but not sure how to identify if the route has a prefix of user-settings.

Of course this may entirely the wrong way to be handling this so entirely open to suggestions!

Comment: Why don't you create saparate components with its path based on route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to test the path name.

`(/^\/user-settings/i).test(this.$route.path);`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a computed property to tell me if the current route's path contains "user-settings" to use in my view with a `v-if="is_user_settings"`.

```
computed: {
  is_user_settings() {
    return this.$route.path.includes('/user-settings/')
  }
}
```

You could also leverage the ["matched" property](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties) of the $route object if you want something cleaner.